# Why is my colorscheme showing weird colors?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I recently (few days...) updated Vim on arch (via the package manager), and I've noticed something about colorschemes has changed. However, I don't understand why I should see color changing if I don't change the `colorscheme`. I've been having `colorscheme pablo` in my `.vimrc` for years now.

With reference to the `vim` filetype, for instance, keywords like `if`/`*map`/`colorscheme` were of a bright yellow, and in **bold**. Recently, I found they are of a pretty lifeless yellow, and not bold. The same holds for the appearance of similar groups in other filetypes.

I don't have a screenshot of a `vim` file before I noticed the change, but I happen to have a screenshot of a C++ file, so here's what I see:

- before
  [image]
- after
  [image]

Is there been a change in Vim which explains the change in what I see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All built-in colorschemes were remade to have mostly uniform look on all platforms (including windows).

In case of pablo, where highlighting was based on first 16 colors, that depend on "terminal colorscheme" (thus different for many(or most?) people) https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/blob/master/legacy_colors/pablo.vim corresponding colors from 256 palette were selected (if terminal reports it supports it).

If you set your terminal to be 16c (`set t_Co=16`, for example) pablo should be almost like it was before.

This was the first step to bring new colorschemes into vim (make old ones "manageable" and provide common experience in all supported platforms).

Comment: Well, I do see some difference, but it't not just about colors. To make an example, even if I `set t_Co=16`, the `using` keyword (see the screenshots in the question) stays non-bold, even though it does become yellow as it was.

Comment: yes indeed, that thing was not properly set (only for gui)

Answer (score 1):

1. Type `:e $VIMRUNTIME/colors/pablo.vim`
2. At top of the file

```
" Name:         pablo
" Author:       Ron Aaron <ron@ronware.org>
" Maintainer:   Original maintainerRon Aaron <ron@ronware.org>
" Website:      https://github.com/vim/colorschemes
" License:      Same as Vim
" Last Updated: Wed May 11 22:56:41 2022
```

3. See `Website` and `Last Updated`. Raise an issue.

Comment: Thanks. [I've done it](https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/issues/170).